# IOS: overwrite a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, nsmutablearray

I have two NSMutableArray: arrayone and arraytwo

arrayone and arraytwo are full of objects, but I want cancel all objects of arrayone and insert in this array all objects of arraytwo. then I want overwrite arrayone with arraytwo.

Comment: A quick look at NSArray documentation...

Comment: So you want to swap contents of both arrays? Or just send all of arrayone's contents to arraytwo, and release arrayone? Sorry, I'm just a little confused about your intentions.

Comment: I want replace all objects of arrayone with objects of arraytwo

Comment: What do you refer to as cancel array? Removing all objects?

Comment: yes removing all objects

Comment: Use the removeAllObjects: method on arrayone, then [arrayone addObjectsFromArray:arraytwo].

Comment: @Avizz92:It is better, if you  post it as answer.

Comment: I just done removeAllObjects: method on arrayone, then [arrayone addObjectsFromArray:arraytwo] but it don't work

Comment: What does or doesn't it do? Make sure both variables point to valid objects, and make sure the arraytwo object actually contains something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A", @"B",nil ];
NSMutableArray *arrayTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"C", @"D",nil ];
```

Now you can remove all objects and insert the new objects like this:

```
[arrayOne removeAllObjects];
[arrayOne addObjectsFromArray:arrayTwo];
```

Or release the array and initialize a new one like this:

```
[arrayOne release];
arrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayTwo];
```

In both cases `NSLog(@"%@",arrayOne);` shows:

```
(
    C,
    D
)
```

Answer (score 0):

arrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayTwo copyitems:YES];